# What is the point with getting a token with a basic auth for my APIs

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication, bearer-token

I've seen a lot a way of authenticating APIs where I get a token that has expiration time with a basic auth. Then I use this token in all my APIs calls to access my API.

First of all, what is the name of this kind of authentifacation ? Token based auth ?

Then what is the point about getting a bearer token when finally, I could just do it with basic auth ?

At a security level, if user / pass in basic auth is compromised, token can be generated easily on demand.

I wonder what is the extra value for that ? If token is JWT, I can get info about user, this is ok, but I could easily do the samething from basic auth information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you for example have some application running on a server that needs to communicate with an API, it's safer to only store the token on that server. In case your server gets compromised, you only need to revoke that token, and your credentials are not leaked.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense ! Thanks